# Issue with returned data of Iconic package

Tags: umbraco

Iconic packages was working very well with version 8.0.2.

After upgrading to 8.1.0, when calling the control, it return string as json

```
({ 
  "icon": "fa-search", 
  "packageId": "8492d996-3934-4cc6-b56a-6ceaac9cba4b" 
})
```

instead of the desired IHtmlString `"i class="fa fa-search"></i>"`. Already tried to remove the package then re-install it but no effects.

What to do to solve this issue? please advice

[image: code snippet]

thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to raise the issue on the iconic github issue tracker as Koben Digital may need to update the package to better support Umbraco 8.1.0:

https://github.com/kobendigital/iconic/issues

Comment: In v8.1.0 the `PropertyValueConverterBase` uses `IPublishedPropertyType` instead `PublishedPropertyType`. I'll release a new version to fix the issue soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version 2.2 has been released. This is compatible with Umbraco 8.1.